# why scrollView.frame = CGRectMake() not work

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!  

override func viewDidLoad() {
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth*3, screenHeight)//this one works
view1.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,400,400)//this one not working
}
```

Is it the viewdidload method not position UIView as I wish?

view1 is subview of scrollView , 
`.contentSize` works for scrollView 
but I cannot position both scrollView and view1 by using `.frame = CGRectMake()`

Anyone help please. Thanks A Lot!

Comment: the `contentSize` and the content's `frame` (incl. its `size`) are two different things. they don't need to be synchronised to each other.

Comment: but how to position the scrollview and view1?

Comment: I am thinking about viewDidLoad method might be the source problem.

Comment: now it works with viewDidAppear(),but When I scroll the scroll view,it shrinks into what it was setup in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The layout is done *after* `viewDidLoad`.

You should also subclass `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and add your "custom" layout (ie. set `view.frame`) there.

Comment: override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        view1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 400, 400)
    }    // it did not work after adding this code

Comment: I drag the view1 from object library into scrollview(in outline document) in storyboard, would this make my view1 to be subview of scrollview automatically?

Comment: Hi Holex,now it works with viewDidAppear(),but When I scroll the scroll view,it shrinks into what it was setup in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can change value directly in storyboard, replacing X and Y values in "Show the Size Inspector" of UIScrollView element

[image: Replace X and Y coordinate]

UPD:
changing position in `viewDidLoad` did not work either, but adding `UIButton` and `Touch Up Inside` works fine. Seems like you can not change origin position in `viewDidLoad`

```
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    @IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        scrollView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(100, 100)
    }
```

UPD2:
to create layout programmatically, refer to code example below:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 400, 400))
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        let uiView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(110, 110, 200, 200))
        uiView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.view.addSubview(uiView)
    }
```

Comment: updated my answer with code example how to setup layout programmatically.